# Respect line breaks in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

It is a doubt that I have tried to solve on my own using different methods, but none has given me the expected result.

The problem comes when I save a variable of type text in the database of my project. It saves it with line breaks, in fact when I try to edit it from one of my views, it respects those jumps. The problem comes when I want to show it in a `blade.php` view, where all the text is without any line break.

I have used different functions such as `nl2br ()` or `str_replace`, and all they do is change the / n to the br tag for line breaks, and instead of applying those line breaks, write them on the screen next to the text.

I do not know if this change or modification to the variable should perhaps be executed on the server and sent to the view, instead of executing in the view `{{nl2br ($ user-> proffile)}}` or with `str_replace`.

First forgiveness for English and thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 23):

You can do the escaping first, using `e()` and then apply `nl2br()`:

```
{{ nl2br(e($user->proffile)) }}
```

`e()` is the function Blade uses when compiling triple brackets

For **Laravel 5**, use this: `{!! nl2br(e($user->proffile)) !!}`

Answer (score 11):

> **Security Warning**: This answer disables security features. Do not use in production!

Just `{!! nl2br($user->proffile) !!}`

`{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}`.

i tested in **laravel 8 blade** and it worked.

Comment: Use `nl2br(e($user->proffile))` to escape user input. Works with all Laravel 8, too.

Comment: I can't believe this outright dangerous answer got as much as 13 upvotes. HOW it's even possible?

Answer (score 10):

An even better approach is to use [plain css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) for this:

```html
<p style="white-space: pre-wrap">{{ $text }}</p>
```

Displaying unescaped text using `{!! ... !!}` is very dangerous [because it allows XSS attacks.](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data)

Comment: This worked great!

Answer (score 4):

In laravel 5 you can use `{!! nl2br(e($user->proffile)) !!}` but this will show the html in the browser.
Doing it this way doesn't show the HTML  `{!! nl2br($user->proffile) !!}`
Last time I used it was in laravel 5.6

Answer (score -2):

Kindly check the SPELLING of `profile` `{{ nl2br(e($user->proffile)) }}`. Sometime people do small mistake. kindly verify in your model.

Comment: Please add this as comment not an answer. Thank you